model for user, companies (departments, teams, jobs)
I want to start a new project and I am not sure which of the DB models to choose (from bellow). I am gonna use Mysql for the BD.
The rules are:

user belongs to one or many companies

one company can have multiple: jobs, departments, teams

the user (on each company):

can belongs to a department

can belongs to a job

can belongs to a team


variant A is this

variant B is this

I think Variant B is more clear...or can I do it better?
